# groupBy filter not working

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

I would like to display the data, based on the date: for eg
[image]

Currently, the code I have come up with is this:

Jade:

```
ul
        li(ng-repeat="history in vm.alertHistoryData | orderBy:'alert-modified-date':true ")
            h4
                | {{ history["alert-modified-date"] | date:"MMM d yyyy" }}
            p
                | {{ history["alert-modified-date"] | date:"h:mm:s a"}}
            div
                p
                    | Priority: {{ history.priority }}
                    | State: {{ history.state }}
```

which gives me result in this format:

- May 3

  data
- May 3

another data

- May 2

data

- May 1

data

Is there a way to group by the date as per the date. I tried using groupBy filter of Angular js , but it doesnt work

```
li(ng-repeat="history in vm.alertHistoryData | orderBy:'alert-modified-date':true | groupBy: 'alert-modified-date")
```

Please help.

Comment: Seems like you are missing an apostrophe at the end of groupBy: 'alert-modified-date

Comment: Na i missed it while pasting it here. in the actual code that isn't the case. I wish it was that simple :)

Comment: You need to use date as an int value and then u can use groupBy filter,otherwise it give you strange result

Comment: so you are suggesting that i should do something like date.valueOf() ?